# 404 Not Found for geoserver in tilelayer

Tags: geoserver

I was using a geoserver tile layer basemap in  with openlayer.

A problem occurred in openlayer where the tile area did not appear, so I checked the geoserver log and saw many logs saying No mapping for GET, but no other error codes were confirmed.

It was normally running well, but when the above error occurred logfile location is geoserver/data/logs and The basemap cache data capacity is about 60 GB.
Can you tell me why this error occurred?

```
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/openstreet/gwc/service/wmts/openstreet:openstreet
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/openstreet/gwc/service/wmts/openstreet:openstreet
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
```

os:CentOS 7.9

geoserver:2.22.2

Tomcat:Apache Tomcat/9.0.73

java-version:java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.10-1.el7_9.x86_6